# How to extract the CSV file name from each line of this file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, regular-expression

I have a file which contains lines like those:

```
-rw-rw-rw 1 root root 6379 May 24 2016 test1.CSV 
-rw-rw-rw 1 root root 23249 May 25 2016 test2.CSV 
-rw-rw-rw 1 root root 2995 May 26 2016 test3.CSV
```

and I need to keep just the CSV file names. I have to use a regex but I don't know which one.

The expected result is "test1.CSV \n test2.CSV \n test3.CSV".

Comment: Have you tried something yourself already? Could you just use `ls` instead of `ls -l`?

Comment: Where do you keep this string, how do you produce it, and what would you want to do with it? If you are looping over all CSV files in a directory, consider using `for file in *.csv; do ...; done`, for example, instead of storing the `ls -l` or `ls` output.

Comment: the file is produce by a system and i have to format it to keep just csv file names. The file contains a lot of line looking like what i have said, so i do keep csv file name ==> test1.csv \n test2.csv \n test3.csv

Comment: @AyoubHammami Are there spaces etc. in the filenames?

Comment: @AyoubHammami: Does "CSV" in the file have to be transformed to "csv" in the output? (Any more changes?)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but relevant reading: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep`

```
grep -io '[^ ]*\.csv' filename
```

> -i, --ignore-case
>                 Ignore case distinctions, so that characters that differ only in case match each other.
>
> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

`[^ ]*\.csv` matches any character but space ending with .csv

I am assuming filename with no space

or you can use `awk`

```
awk '{print $(NF)}' filename | grep -i '\.csv'
```

variable `$(NF)` is the last field in every line

Comment: you can accept it as answer, if it solves your problem, as it will help other persons in future if in case

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk '$NF~/CSV$/ {print $NF}'  file
```

- extracts the lines end with CSV and prints the last field

Comment: thanks but i mean i have file with something like this :                                             -rw-rw-rw   1     root     root      6379 May 24  2016 test1.CSV
-rw-rw-rw   1     root     root     23249 May 25  2016 test2.CSV
-rw-rw-rw   1     root     root      2995 May 26  2016 test3.CSV                         and i need to keep just csv file name, i have to use a regex but i dont know which one

Comment: @AyoubHammami try my update

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `[^ ]* *$`

Or simply, if relevant, `gawk '{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ' awk' :

```
awk '{print $9}' files
```

It will work whenever the filename is the 9th field in the line.